# How to Do ToLower on a potentially Nullable Field in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am for the first time trying to use non nullable feature in C#.

I have a EF model like this

```
public class TestTable
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string? Name {get; set;}
}
```

now I want to do a search on "Name" but I don't care about case

```
context.TestTable.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower() == "bob").ToList();
```

Of course it is giving me a warning of possible null.

I am not sure what to do in this situation. In all likely hood I guess I could use "!" as this field should actually be "non null" in the database but for whatever reason it was marked as "nullable" and to change this at the database would involve too many people.

Though it does give me a good chance on what if this column is truly a nullable column, but I need to do a "tolower" on it how best do you do it?

Do you check for not null first?

Comment: `Where(x => x.Name != null && x.Name.ToLower() == "bob")`?

Comment: Okay that is what I was thinking I would have to do but was not sure if there was some fancy way of doing it.

Comment: `Where(x => x.Name?.ToLower() == "bob")` _may_ work, depending on if EFCore can translate that into SQL or not.

Comment: Yeah, that was the first thing I tried with the question mark, but I could not even get past the compiler as I don't think it would translate it property to satisfy the where clause.

Comment: Have you considered changing the collation of the column to a case-insensitive collation? That would be much more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

before adding to Lowercase Function on nullable field in EF be sure to validate if it is not null. you can use something like this to get the desired result:

```
var result = context.TestTable
    .Where(x => x.Name != null && x.Name.ToLower() == "bob")
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Great, that is what I thought I would have to do but wanted to see if there was something else I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string function to check whether string is null or not.

```
var result = context.TestTable
.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Name) 
            && x.Name.Equals("bob", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
.ToList();
```